# pandas Finding IDs that only have NAs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am looking to get a series/DataFrame of IDs that have only NAs within the data.

The data looks something like this:

| ID | Score | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 95 | 1-1-2022 |
| 1 | nan | 1-1-2022 |
| 1 | nan | 2-1-2022 |
| 2 | nan | 1-1-2022 |
| 2 | 100 | 2-1-2022 |
| 3 | nan | 1-1-2022 |
| 3 | nan | 1-1-2022 |
| 3 | nan | 2-1-2022 |

So in this case, I would only want to grab ID 3 and have one instance of it in the newly created DF.

So far, I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                'Score':[95,nan,nan,nan,100,nan,nan,nan],
                 'Date':['1-1-2022','1-1-2022','2-1-2022','1-1-2022','2-1-2022',
                         '1-1-2022','1-1-2022', '2-1-2022']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('ID',dropna=False)['Score'].count())
df3 = df2[df2['Score'] == 0]
```

But this does not seem to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what exactly does not work? can you edit your question so that we can see what you get and what you expected?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is a series or df of the IDs that hit the criteria stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a boolean vector checking if 'Score' column is `nan` and then you can groupby your 'ID' column and use `transform('all')`.

This will return `True` / `False` to all rows of the ID that are `nan` in all rows.

```
>>> df['Score'].isna().groupby(df['ID']).transform('all')

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: Score, dtype: bool
```

Using this boolean you can filter your dataframe and get ID 3 in a new df:

```
ids_with_all_none = df[df['Score'].isna().groupby(df['ID']).transform('all')]

   ID  Score      Date
5   3    NaN  1-1-2022
6   3    NaN  1-1-2022
7   3    NaN  2-1-2022
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you mean exactly, if not please provide what you expect as ouput. But to select the rows with Nans for the score you can use:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.Score.isna()]
```

output:
[image]

the you can select the IDs simply with:

```
df3 = df2.groupby('ID').first()
df3
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is going to work fine if you replace `nan` with `None`. Try this out:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                'Score':[95,None,None,None,100,None,None,None],
                 'Date':['1-1-2022','1-1-2022','2-1-2022','1-1-2022','2-1-2022',
                         '1-1-2022','1-1-2022', '2-1-2022']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('ID',dropna=False, as_index=False)['Score'].count())
df3 = df2[df2['Score'] == 0]
print(df3['ID'])
```